# Override many2one with many2many

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I try to override many2one field with many2many

```py
 property_product_pricelist = fields.Many2many('product.pricelist',
                                                      string="Sale Pricelist",
                                                      help="This pricelist will be used, instead of the default one, for sales to the current partner")
```

and i get this error when try to save values

```
File "/home//workspace/odoo-9.0/openerp/models.py", line 5384, in _browse
    env.prefetch[cls._name].update(ids)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

also i tryid like this

```py
property_product_pricelist = fields.Many2many('product.pricelist', column1='partner_id', column2='pricelist_id')
```

but get

```
ProgrammingError: column product_pricelist_res_partner_rel.pricelist_id does not exist
```

LINE 1: SELECT product_pricelist_res_partner_rel.pricelist_id, produ...

Comment: I would suggest you not to do that because if a Many2one field already exists, it must be used at many different places and you will have errors everywhere, because a singleton is expected instead of a list. You should create another field instead.

Comment: What you are doing is bad because you will break the logic.Ask you the question `why I need a many2many field ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I came up with.

- create a many2many field totally new
- write an onchange method which sets the value of the original field (here the many2one) to the new many2many field

```py
multiply_pricelists_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'product.pricelist', string='Multiply Pricelists')

    @api.onchange('property_product_pricelist')
    @api.multi
    def pricelist_change(self):
        self.multiply_pricelists_ids =  self.property_product_pricelist
```